# Wrong Output : counting the string

Tags: c++, string-length

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char a[10001],b[10001];
    int tot,s1,s2;
    cin>>tot;
    while(tot!=0) {
        gets(a);
        gets(b);
        s1= strlen(a);
        s2= strlen(b);
        cout<<s1<<s2<<endl;
        tot--;
        s1=0;
        s2=0;
    }
}
```

this is a program to find length of two strings , with cases also entered 
Input :

```
4
abcd
xyz
abcd
bcda
aabc
acaa
Codechef
elfedcc
```

Expected output

```
43
44
44
87
```

but output is

```
04
34
44
48
```

Why?

Comment: The compiler is punishing you for using `gets` (or else there's still a new-line in the input buffer after `cin>>tot;`).

Comment: [`gets` is one thing to avoid in C/C++.](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-56.html)

Comment: Do note that `gets` is going to be removed soon (libc++ has already done so in its C++1y support).

Comment: hint: use `std::string`, no need for 1001-sized arrays, plus, it has a `size()` member!

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comment, the compiler is punishing you for using `gets`<sup>1</sup>. I wasn't going to write an actual answer, but the answers you're getting seem to be trying to cover up the problems with the code, without actually fixing anything.

First: **never** use `gets`. There's simply no way to use it safely, and no excuse for even trying. It's just a badly designed function and we'd all be better off if it had never existed.

Second, in C++ there's *almost* never a good reason to use arrays of `char` for strings. `strlen` is pretty much the same way. These aren't as dangerous or horrible as `gets` but real reasons to use them in C++ (outside of things like extremely limited embedded systems) is sufficiently rare that until you know what you're doing and why, it's probably best to forget that they even exist as well.

While you're at it, using a `while` loop (counting down, no less) in a case like this mostly just obfuscates the code while gaining nothing in return. For that matter, using a variable name like `tot` instead of (for example) `total` or (better) `pair_count` is kind of silly as well.

So, having gotten bombastic about what you *shouldn't* do, what would I suggest instead? First, if you're going to use `stream >> var` type input, try to use it consistently. If you're going to read lines instead, try to do that consistently. In this case, you can use either one, but mixing the two leads to exactly the sort of problem you're having right now. As such, it's best to avoid that whole area if you can (and you almost always can).

For this, I'd use `>>` throughout, use `std::string` to hold the strings, and a `for` loop to execute the fixed number of iterations:

```
int word_count;
std::cin >> pair_count;

for (int i=0; i<pair_count; i++) {
    std::string a, b;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    std::cout << a.size() << b.size() << '\n';
}
```

Unlike the other recommendations you've gotten, this is typesafe (`scanf` and company don't even try to be), safe from buffer overflows (`gets` never is, and while `scanf` and company can be, they aren't when used as the other answers have recommended). It's also shorter and simpler without adding mostly-unexplained patches to cover up the real problems in the code.

If the preceding sounds harsh, I apologize for that. Unfortunately, that's sometimes just about necessary to get the point across, and at least to me, this seems like one of those times.

---

<sub>1. The zeroth commandment: thou shalt not use gets. If you do, you shall surely die (but not as soon as everybody maintaining your code wishes you had).</sub>

Comment: :) while you were cooking up this blog post, I was writing the same code!  Only, in a buffered context, it may be better to use `endl` over newline.

Comment: @xtofl: Yeah, I saw your answer pop up right after I posted my rant. Maybe if you'd posted a minute sooner, the world wouldn't see me seeming so confrontational, but such is life I guess.

Comment: I have to admit, seeing `gets` and array literals, I didn't even take the time to scan for OP error...

Comment: why are you using for and not while  ? xtofl used while too

Comment: @SanchitBansal: If you're going to execute a loop for a specific number of iterations, `for` is *much* more idiomatic. A `while` loop is best reserved for situations that don't fit a `for` loop as well.

Comment: @SanchitBansal: @xtofl hesitated to revert to a `for` since he thought the most important point was to use the formatted stream extractors.

Answer (score 2):

You should really try using the standard template library for string things:

```
std::string a, b;
int numberToAsk = 0;
cin >> numberToAsk;

while(numberToAsk!=0) {
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << a.size() << ", " << b.size() << endl;
    --numberToAsk;
}
```

(also make sure to use [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) in stead of plain arrays!)

Also, you can avoid needing to ask for the number of entries upfront by just checking if standard input is still ok; your program will end as soon as you end the input stream (e.g. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> or <kbd>F6</kbd> on windows, or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> on linux):

```
while(cin >> a >> b) {
   cout << a.size() << ", " << b.size() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Your original answer was good, but your edit...much less good. You don't want `while (cin.good())`. You want `while (cin >> a >> b)`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: great tip; some time in the past I moved towards using `good()`; since I don't remember why, I updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

```
cin>>tot;
```

This code does not consume '\n' character. So the first gets call reads line between "4" and "\n". To see it you may try input

```
4abcd
xyz
abcd
bcda
aabc
acaa
Codechef
elfedcc
```

Answer (score 0):

change cin to  scanf works

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char a[10001],b[10001];
    int tot,s1,s2;
    scanf("%d\n",&tot);
    while(tot!=0) {
        gets(a);
        gets(b);
        s1= strlen(a);
        s2= strlen(b);
        cout<<s1<<s2<<endl;
        tot--;
        s1=0;
        s2=0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Do it this way

```
scanf("%d ",%t);
```

For taking in no. of inputs. That space avoids '\n' character that you enter after entering a number input which is taken by first string. Rest of your code can be done as it is.

You need to include cstdio header. `#include<cstdio>`